# Using dictionaries to create a variable as a variable name

Tags: python-3.x

I've been researching this for a while, and have seen some questions similar to mine, but I don't quite understand / think they're what I'm looking for. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
def run():
    cost = input("enter cost")
    size = input("enter size")
    print("For color, 1 = red, 2 = blue, 3 = green, enter one")
    color = input("enter color")

    shoe1 = [cost, size, color]


    repeat = input("Do you want to order another shoe? Y/N")

    if repeat == "Y" or repeat == "y":
        run()
```

But then, save shoe1 so that it isn't redefined when we re-run the function, and that a new list is defined, maybe shoe2 (Or any variable name). So that at the end we can list all the shoes, and specifications of the shoes that were ordered. Other questions said that a dictionary should be used for this, how might I do that?.All help appreciated, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thus far you don't have a dictionary to even try putting things into - I would recommend starting by changing that. Actually a list might be a better fit, `shoes[0]` rather than `shoes['shoe1']`. You should refactor to give a function that takes input and returns a single shoe, and a separate loop that calls it repeatedly.

Comment: so you want to " **list** all the shoes"? I'd recommend a `list` for that...

Comment: So if I change my variable from shoe1 to shoes[0], how do I change it so that next time the function runs it'll store the next list as shoes[1]? Am I on the right track? So sorry, I'm new to this. I think you guys are right, and a list is correct @jonrsharpe

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: Thank you. TOTALLY get it now, I'm an idiot *facepalm* @jonrsharpe